# What is the difference between rb and r+b modes in file objects

Tags: python, file, file-io, pickle

I am using pickle module in Python and trying different file IO modes:

```
# works on windows.. "rb"
with open(pickle_f, 'rb') as fhand:
        obj = pickle.load(fhand)

# works on linux.. "r"
with open(pickle_f, 'r') as fhand:
        obj = pickle.load(fhand)

# works on both "r+b"
with open(pickle_f, 'r+b') as fhand:
        obj = pickle.load(fhand)
```

I never read about "r+b" mode anywhere, but found mentioning about it in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

I am getting `EOFError` on Linux if I use `"rb"` mode and on Windows if `"r"` is used. I just gave `"r+b"` mode a shot and it's working on both.

What's `"r+b"` mode? What's the difference between "rb" and "r+b"? Why does it work when the others don't?

Comment: Hope this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9644285/9905745) will help, it explains the differences between `'r'` and `'rb'` in python3.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

`r+` is used for reading, and writing mode. `b` is for binary.
`r+b` mode is open the binary file in read or write mode.
You can read more [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: Please read this: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files It would answer your question

Comment: if I grant write privileges to a file obj where its not required, will that lead to any security issue in future?

Comment: It is risky. Especially in windows as it modifies the file every time we open it

Answer (score 28):

`r` opens for reading, whereas `r+` opens for reading and writing. The `b` is for binary.

This is spelled out in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

> The most commonly-used values of mode are `'r'` for reading, `'w'` for writing (truncating the file if it already exists), and `'a'` for appending (which on some Unix systems means that all writes append to the end of the file regardless of the current seek position). If mode is omitted, it defaults to `'r'`. The default is to use text mode, which may convert `'\n'` characters to a platform-specific representation on writing and back on reading. Thus, when opening a binary file, you should append `'b'` to the mode value to open the file in binary mode, which will improve portability. (Appending `'b'` is useful even on systems that don’t treat binary and text files differently, where it serves as documentation.) See below for more possible values of mode.
>
> Modes `'r+'`, `'w+'` and `'a+'` open the file for updating (note that `'w+'` truncates the file). Append `'b'` to the mode to open the file in binary mode, on systems that differentiate between binary and text files; on systems that don’t have this distinction, adding the `'b'` has no effect.

Comment: so, you mean, `r+b` wouldn't make any difference on Linux but does on windows.. moreover, what's the difference between "rb" and "r+b"..

Comment: I'm not sure you read this answer carefully, @Iamcool. It answers all your questions.

Answer (score 9):

My understanding is that adding `r+` opens for both read and write (just like `w+`, though as pointed out in the comment, will truncate the file). The `b` just opens it in binary mode, which is supposed to be less aware of things like line separators (at least in C++).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, "w+" will erase the file if it exists, and then open it for reading and writing. It's not the same as "r+".

Answer (score 4):

> On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so
>   there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb', and 'r+b'. Python on Windows
>   makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line
>   characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data
>   is read or written. This behind-the-scenes modification to file data
>   is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll corrupt binary data like that
>   in JPEG or EXE files. Be very careful to use binary mode when reading
>   and writing such files. On Unix, it doesn’t hurt to append a 'b' to
>   the mode, so you can use it platform-independently for all binary
>   files.

Source: [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)