# Cherrypy base64 image encoding not working as expected

Tags: python, image, base64, cherrypy, data-uri

## The Problem:

I have been playing around with CherryPy for the past couple of days but I'm still having some trouble with getting images to work how I could expect them to. I can save an uploaded image as a jpg without issue but I can't convert it to a base64 image properly. Here's the simple server I wrote:

### server.py

```
#server.py
import os 
import cherrypy #Import framework


frameNumber = 1
lastFrame = ''
lastFrameBase64 = ''

class Root (object):

    def upload(self, myFile, username, password):
        global frameNumber
        global lastFrameBase64
        global lastFrame
        size = 0
        lastFrameBase64 = ''
        lastFrame = ''
        while True:
            data = myFile.file.read(8192)
            if not data:
                break
            size += len(data)
            lastFrame += data
            lastFrameBase64 += data.encode('base64').replace('\n','')
        

        f = open('/Users/brian/Files/git-repos/learning-cherrypy/tmp_image/lastframe.jpg','w')
        f.write(lastFrame)
        f.close()
        f = open('/Users/brian/Files/git-repos/learning-cherrypy/tmp_image/lastframe.txt','w')
        f.write(lastFrameBase64)
        f.close()

        cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        print "Image received!"
        frameNumber = frameNumber + 1
        out = "{\"status\":\"%s\"}"
        return out % ( "ok" )
    upload.exposed = True

cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '192.168.1.14',
                        'server.socket_port': 8080,
                       })
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # CherryPy always starts with app.root when trying to map request URIs
    # to objects, so we need to mount a request handler root. A request
    # to '/' will be mapped to HelloWorld().index().
    cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

When I view the `lastframe.jpg` file, the image renders perfectly. However, when I take the text string found in `lastframe.txt` and prepend the proper data-uri identifier `data:image/jpeg;base64,` to the base64 string, I get a broken image icon in the webpage I'm trying to show the image in.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9....." >
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried using another script to convert my already-saved jpg image into a data-uri and it works. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in the server example b/c this code gives me a string that works as a data-uri:

### Working Conversion

```
jpgtxt = open('tmp_image/lastframe.jpg','rb').read().encode('base64').replace('\n','')

f = open("jpg1_b64.txt", "w")
f.write(jpgtxt)
f.close()
```

So basically it comes down to how is the `data` variable taken from `myFile.file.read(8192)` is different from the `data` variable taken from `open('tmp_image/lastframe.jpg','rb')` I read that the `rb` mode in the open method tells python to read the file as a binary file rather than a string. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746954/what-is-the-difference-between-rb-and-rb-modes-in-file-objects) where I got that.

### Summary

In summary, I don't know enough about python or the cherrypy framework to see how the actual data is stored when reading from the `myFile` variable and how the data is store when reading from the output of the `open()` method. Thanks for taking the time to look at this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) works by taking every 3 bytes of input and producing 4 characters. But what happens when the input isn't a multiple of 3 bytes? There's special processing for that, appending `=` signs to the end. But that's only supposed to happen at the end of the file, not in the middle. Since you're reading 8192 bytes at a time and encoding them, and 8192 is not a multiple of 3, you're generating corrupt output.

Try reading 8190 bytes instead, or read and encode the entire file at once.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you so much! It worked. Is there any way I could have come to this realization on my own?

Comment: @anglinb you might have inspected the output and seen the `=` signs yourself, but that assumes you're familiar with how Base64 is supposed to look.

Comment: That's kind of what I thought. I did look at the different outputs but did not realize the extra ` = ` signs