# Error is being shown when I run the code and I am unable to figure out the second question

Tags: python

```
import pickle
med = {}
medfile = open("Medicines.dat","wb")
while True:
    name = input("Enter the name: ")
    company = input("Enter the company: ")
    chemical = input("Enter the chemical: ")
    price = input("Enter the price: ")
    med['name'] = name
    med['company'] = company
    med['chemical'] = chemical
    med['price'] = price
    pickle.dump(med,medfile)
    ans = input("Wouldyou like to add more(y/n) ")
    if ans == "y":
        continue
    elif ans == "n":
        break

medfile = open("Medicines.dat","r+")
print(pickle.load(medfile))
medfile.close()
```

The question is as follows:
A binary file "Medicines.dat has structure [Name, Company, Chemical, Price] a) Write a user defined function add_data() to input the data for a record and store in the file b) Write a function search() which accepts a company name and displays the details of all the Medicines by that company

Comment: Hi enchantedHero, welcome to SO! Thanks for posting your code :) What error exactly are you seeing?

Comment: #Input
Enter the name: g
Enter the company: h
Enter the chemical: n
Enter the price: 20
Wouldyou like to add more(y/n) n

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(pickle.load(medfile))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: Great! I would add that to the question if I were you; folks usually look there first for context

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems here:

---

### 1st Opening the file correctly

`medfile = open("Medicines.dat","r+")`

You mean `rb`. The difference is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15746971/2329988), but pickle parsing requires the file to be in "binary" mode, hence the "b".

---

### 2nd Closing the file correctly

You should close the file before re-opening it for writing, as a matter of best practce. (`medfile.close()`). Even better, python will take care of when the file gets closed if you use the ["with" syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282967/how-to-open-a-file-using-the-open-with-statement) to create a context

---

### 3rd Having the right values

While the code should now run, I doubt it will do what you want. Your query asks "Wouldyou [sic] like to add more(y/n)", but it does not look to me like it is adding **more** values, since you use the same "med" dictionary over and over. Consider how the "new" fields would ever be distinguishable from the "old" ones, based on their key

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it with a list?

Comment: As in
'med = {}'

Comment: Let's see, 'med = {}' makes a *dictionary*. A dictionary stores a key/value pair, which let's you do things like med['name'] = 'dogman. The *key* in that example is 'name', and the 'value' is 'dogman'. I would strongly recommend doing some reading on basic data structures (I find the official docs a little dense for a noobie, but there's a ton of great resources on the web. If your learning python, i bet your teacher has some recs)

Comment: A *list* is a just an ordered collection of things. a = ['A','B','C'] . a[0] is A, a[1] is 'B', so on. There's no "mapping" between anything. In your case, it might make sense to have a *list of dictionaries*. Where you've written 'med = {}', you could make a list, 'med = []'. Then in the loop, (after while True), make a new dictionary, 'new_entry = {}', and put your key value pairs in it. Before writing to the database, you could add the new entry to your list ('list.append(new_entry)'), and then write out the list instead of the individual entry

Comment: But that's one of many many ways, it may be quite helpful to take a look at the datastructures and come up with a solution that makes sense to you :)