# SignedJwtAssertionCredentials on AppEngine doesn't recognize PEM key

Tags: google-app-engine, openssl, pycrypto, pem, pkcs#12

SignedJwtAssertionCredentials on appengine (with pycrypto 2.6) doesn't support the PKCS12 format, therefore I'm trying to use PEM keys instead, as suggested everywhere..

this is my code:

```
  f = file(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), KEY_FILE), "r")
  key = f.read()
  f.close()

  credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, key,
      scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
  http = httplib2.Http()
  http = credentials.authorize(http)
```

and the `KEY_FILE` is a PEM key, converted with the command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in privatekey.p12 -nodes -nocerts > privatekey.pem
```

but I still get this error, as if it didn't recognize that's a PEM key:

```
NotImplementedError: PKCS12 format is not supported by the PyCrpto library. 
Try converting to a "PEM" (openssl pkcs12 -in xxxxx.p12 -nodes -nocerts > privatekey.pem) or using PyOpenSSL if native code is an option.
```

same error if I pass just the filename to the constructor (without reading the contents of the file)

any idea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yeah, the error is hugely misleading.  What you're doing is fine; just remove the header from the PEM file so that it begins with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`, or run the following command over it:

```
openssl pkcs8 -nocrypt -in privatekey.pem -passin pass:notasecret -topk8 -out pk.pem
```

Comment: I have a similar problem and I tried your solution too but I am getting a new error. Do you have a solution? Please check [PyCrypto Errors with x.p12 file from Google Developer Console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25571504/1443563)

Answer (score 6):

for those interested, I ended up compiling a short tutorial on how to use the Google+ Domains APIs with python on App Engine, you can find it here:
https://gist.github.com/vircheck/6292176

It's also applicable to other APIs based on service accounts, such as the Drive API etc..

Comment: I have a similar problem and I tried your solution too but I am getting a new error. Do you have a solution? Please check [PyCrypto Errors with x.p12 file from Google Developer Console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25571504/1443563)