# Google Drive Service Account Access on Google App Engine to Impersonate Users

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to gain service account access to to the Google Drive API. I followed the [Google Drive SDK example](https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts#google_app_engine_project_service_accounts) when I was building my application. My code resembles the example almost exactly:

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
      build = createDriveService(user)
      searchFile = build.files().get(fileId='FILEID').execute()
      self.response.write(searchFile)

def createDriveService(userEmail):
    API_KEY = 'APIKEY' 
    credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(
        scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
        sub=userEmail)
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)

    return build('drive', 'v2', http=http, developerKey=API_KEY)
```

When I call visit my GAE page the error in the logs that I am getting is:

```
<"File not found: FILEID">
```

I know the file ID exists as I copied it from the UI. I am using the simple Key access for the variable API_KEY. Should I be validating my application a different way?

**EDIT1**:

I've tried following various other StackOverflow. One of which involves using the SignedJwtAssertionCredentials and converting the .p12 key to a .pem key. After this change I am getting a

```
 cannot import SignedJwtAsserionCredentials
```

error. From there I made sure to include the pycrypto library in my `app.yaml`. Any Idea?

**EDIT2**

I have successfully impersonated users on app engine. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993604/signedjwtassertioncredentials-on-appengine-doesnt-recognize-pem-key) previously answered question and it worked.

Comment: The key information was the 'sub' parameter to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the user part of your code, bacause you use a Google App Engine project user account. 
See [this doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts) on how to use and find this account. You can also fnd this account using :

```
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
logging.info('service account : ' + app_identity.get_service_account_name())
```

Make sure you have given this project user account access to your drive file or folder!

My code looks like this :

```
def createDriveService():

    SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    API_KEY = 'AIzaSyB9UkK4OH5Z_E4v3Qp6bay6QEgGpzou3bc'     # GAE
    credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope=SCOPE)
    logging.info('using service account : ' + app_identity.get_service_account_name())
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    return build('drive', 'v2', http=http, developerKey=API_KEY)
```

Comment: The reason that the user is a variable in my code is because I am mirroring [this example](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation) of how to use domain wide delegation and impersonate other users.

Comment: OK. I'am not familiair with this option.

Comment: Also, when I used code, I received the same error (after changing the API Key)

Comment: When you use my code, did you add the service account to your file to give it access?

Comment: Yes but that will not fit my use case. Thank you. Any insight into the user impersonation? Currently, I can run my program using SignedJwtAssertionCredentials from the terminal, but since I want the application to run on GAE, I cannot have a downloaded key. Any thoughts?