# Read all types of files python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, readfile

I'm working on an application in Python 3, but what I want is to upload any type of file. e. g. in c function :

```
fopen()
```

you can load any file type. Is there any way to do that? already tried with :

```
open ()
```

but it throws me errors:

> UnicodeDecodeError:' charmap' code cant decode byte.

Help :(

Comment: You're opening non-text files in text mode. You need binary mode.

Comment: use `"b"` in `open(..., "rb")` to open in binary mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open and read a binary file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35000687/how-to-open-and-read-a-binary-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

`f = open(file, mode='rb')` opens `file` in binary mode.  `f.read()` then returns the file contents as bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Command `open()` as default opens it text mode which tries to decode text to unicode.

If you have to open other file then better use binary mode.

Use `"b"` in `open(filename, "rb")` to do it.

Python 3 doc: [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)