# converting .png images to base64

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to encode *.png* images to base64 so people don't need to have my pictures/change pictures to view it.

I have searched a lot and tried many things, my last attempt got me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "random.py", line 100, in <module>
    convert(r"C:\Users\simon\Desktop\pictures\pizza_pics\meat_lovers.png")
  File "random.py", line 91, in convert
    data = f.read()
  File "C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\c  p1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 30: chara  cter maps to <undefined>
```

I looked into what 0x8d is but found nothing that worked or that I really understood.

This is my code:

```
#encodes the images from .jpg or .png files to base64 string(lets others view the image)
def convert(image):
    img = open(image)
    data = img.read()

    string = base64.b64encode(data)
    convert = base64.b64encode(string)

    img = Image.open(r"C:\Users\simon\Desktop\pictures\pizza_pics\meat_lovers.png", "UTF-8")
    img.write(convert)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    convert(r"C:\Users\simon\Desktop\pictures\pizza_pics\meat_lovers.png")

#shows the image
img.thumbnail((350, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = img)
label_image = tk.Label(image = photo)
label_image.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=(5, 95))
```

Comment: thank you for editing the code for me, i know now what to do haha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cant really put my finger on what you are doing wrong, but the code seems to be more complex then it has to be.

Instead of doing the read operations, let `base64` module handle it for you

```
import base64
with open('noaa19-161015.png', 'rb') as fp, open('test.b64', 'w') as fp2:
    base64.encode(fp, fp2)

with open('test.b64', 'rb') as fp, open('test.png', 'wb') as fp2:
    base64.decode(fp, fp2)
```

Also noticed that you are trying to encode a already encoded `string`
look at the row `base64.b64encode(string)`

Comment: so the first with encodes it and the second decodes it? i see now, thank you!

Comment: do i have to put both into my coding or only the encoding part of it?

Comment: It depends. If you want to do both, then use both. 

The upper part encodes the binary-picture into Base64, the other part decodes base64 into binary

Comment: I used 'wb' for `fp2`

Comment: the b64 file only contains charachters. Probably no diffrence in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

while you're opening a not txt-like file, using 'rb' will avoid that error.

Comment: oh so "rb" is for images without text? interesting, thank you!

Comment: for an explanation for the use of 'rb' have look at this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644110/difference-between-parsing-a-text-file-in-r-and-rb-mode/9644141#9644141

Im running Linux, so there might be a difference there

Comment: ah i'm on windows using that too i think, not sure to be honest but i'll take a look thank you!