# Python- Read values from CSV file and add columns values to REST API iteration calls

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to python, I'm reading csv file having 2 columns as ID and Filepath (headers not present). Trying to enter the ID into the URL and filepath into the below rest api call. Can't get the values of the row.
If the value at row[0] is TDEVOPS-1 it's returning numeric value.

```
import csv

filename1 = 'E:\\Upload-PM\\attachment.csv'
with open(filename1, 'rb') as csvfile:
    datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvfile.readlines():
        urlvalue = "https://<url>.atlassian.com/rest/api/3/issue/" + str({row[0]}) + "/attachments"
        url = urlvalue
        print(url)
        headers = {"X-Atlassian-Token": "nocheck"}
        files = {'file': open(row[1], 'rb')}
        r = requests.post(url, auth=('<email>','<token>'), files=files, headers=headers)
        print(r.status_code)
        print(r.text)
```

Input:

```
TDEVOPST-5,E:\Upload-PM\att.csv
TDEVOPST-2,E:\Upload-PM\att2.csv
TDEVOPST-3,E:\Upload-PM\att3.csv
```

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me what is the exact error you are getting. But did you try using format?

```
urlvalue = "https://<url>.atlassian.com/rest/api/3/issue/{}/attachments".format(row[0])
```

UPDATE - corresponding to the comments, the issue seems to be with how you read the csv file. Id recommend to use the “r” flag for better string parsing. See - [Difference between parsing a text file in r and rb mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644110/difference-between-parsing-a-text-file-in-r-and-rb-mode) for more details

In addition I'd suggest to use python `os.path` to make sure the path is valid

Comment: made the update here

Comment: probably, as I want to read the row column value then the fetch should be different. I'm using row[0] which is giving me the T into ASCI as 84, whereas I want to have the whole string of the column 1 row 1

Comment: Oh Understand the issue. You should use just “r” flag when read. See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644110/difference-between-parsing-a-text-file-in-r-and-rb-mode

Comment: Got it. Did changes to 'r' and worked well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your file has not header then try to read it as symply .txt file:

```
attachment = ["TDEVOPST-5,E:\\Upload-PM\\att.csv","TDEVOPST-2,E:\\Upload-PM\\att2.csv","TDEVOPST-3,E:\\Upload-PM\\att3.csv"]

fn = "temp.txt"
with open(fn, "w") as f:
  f.write("\n".join(attachment))

with open(fn,"r") as f:
  for row in f:
    print(row.replace("\n",""))   # optional string for test
    els = row.split(",")
    print(els[0],"->",els[1])  # optional string for test
```

Then you can use: `els[0],els[1]` as you need. May be like this:

```
urlvalue = f"https://<url>.atlassian.com/rest/api/3/issue/{els[0]}/attachments"
```