# Correct way to use with open on xml files and ET.parse

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, with-statement

For reading in XML files with `with open` and `ET.parse`, should we use 'r', 'rb', something else, or does it not matter?

```
with open('something.xml', '??') as f:
    tree = ET.parse(f)
```

Edit:

The reason I want to open this way is because the filepath I have may be an s3 path and ET.parse does not appear to support S3 paths. However, using the package s3fs, I was able to load the file:

```
import s3fs
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
with fs.open(file) as f:
    tree = ET.parse(f)
```

Comment: xml is usually plain text, so just `open('filename')` should work (which defaults to `'r'`)

Comment: No I'm wondering if there's a difference in the output if I use 'r' vs 'rb', as both methods seem to allow me to load the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to open a file to pass it to ElementTree, it is smart enough to open for itself using the "rb" mode.

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644110/difference-between-parsing-a-text-file-in-r-and-rb-mode), It seems that the preferrable way, is to use "r", because the XML file is supposed to contain text encoded data. But, since the [ElementTree](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L557) uses "rb" mode, I dont think that there is a lot of difference.